# How to edit X axsis for matplotlib when X axsis is timedate month in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe using datetime as index. This is done by using .rersample() to month so it only shows the last day of a month. However, when I try to plot a bar chart with this timedate on the x-axis using matplotlib, it doesn't show the correct month. It should show from January 2017 to December 2017, but it shows from Feburary 2017 to January 2018.

Could Someone teach me how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sure we can help as long as you add your code.

Comment: And don't add data/code/error messages as images. Post the text directly here on SO.